# Python Requests: Website asks to 'Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page'

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am running the code below with requests on python 2.7 on OSX

```
html_response = requests.get(website_variable)
if html_response.status_code != 200:
    print "There was an error! Status code = " + str(html_response.status_code)
    print html_response.content
    sys.exit(1)
```

I get an HTML response of 503 from the website I am trying to get the response from. I also found a response from the website to turn on Javascript.

```
<noscript><h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1></noscript>
```

Am I doing trying to gather information from this website in the correct way? Do I need to turn on a setting or feature in the requests module?

Comment: Have a look at [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) - you need more than just `requests` for JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you @bastelflp! It seems I instead need to use the dryscrape or selenium module to interact with Javascript. From this thread it seems the requests module does not have this support.

Comment: Try setting a different User-Agent header. Usually, the website treats the request as a non-browser one by checking HTTP headers. Default user agent of `requests` is [`python-requests/2.25.0`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L826).